# WebApi - Read GET parameters passed from jQuery GET to object

Tags: jquery, json, post, asp.net-web-api, get

When calling a REST service with jquery, I can pass a POJO object to $.get(...) call, and jquery will serialize the object's properties to GET QueryString.

My REST service is developed using WebAPI, and I'm wondering if I can make it automatically deserialize querystring parameters to an object.

More precisely:

If I have a POST method, I can deserialize the json from message body as below

I have the following jQuery code

```
var dataObj // my POJO
j$.post('/api/myserv', dataObj, function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    // ....
```

And the WebApi endpoint

```
' MyEntity class has same structure as POJO object
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal entity As MyEntity) As HttpResponseMessage 
    ' here I have entity instantiated and setup
```

When using jquery get, and passing POJO object:

```
var dataObj // my POJO
j$.get('/api/myserv', dataObj, function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    // ....
```

This translates to

```
GET /api/myserv?prop1=val1&prop2=val2&...
```

In WebApi I would like to instantiate an object as with POST

```
' MyEntity class hadata from uri, s same structure as POJO object
Public Function GetValue(<FromURI()> ByVal entity As MyEntity) As HttpResponseMessage 
    ' but here the entity is null
```

To be able to read I have to have a param for every prop in POJO object, like

```
' MyEntity class hadata from uri, s same structure as POJO object
Public Function GetValue(prop1 As .., prop2 as ..., ) As HttpResponseMessage
```

Is there any way to be able to read all params from get in a single object, as it'spossib;e with POST from body?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[FromUri]` before the object in the `WebAPI` method parameter.  Take a look at [`Parameter Binding`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) here.

Set your jquery call up like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { prop1: 1, prop2: "two" },
    success: function (result) {
        //handle
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I already did it (see my question), and it didn't worked. But now I tried again, and it did worked now. Strange. Thanks for answer, that made me try again.